# How to write generic hook for functions in C?

Tags: c, hook

I want to write a hook function that is called whenever a function is called in my program to gather some statistics about the arguments of the function. For example:

```
void hook(function f, ...){
    //some statistics here
    f(...);
}
int main(){
    foo(1, 2);
}
```

So instead of calling `foo` directly, it will call hook instead with `foo` as its first argument and `1, 2` as extra arguments.

Is there anything similar to this in C? Can I achieve this goal in C in any other way?

Comment: In c you need to have a function pointer with an ellipsis in it's signature.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code I wrote is more of a pseudo code than a real one. I just want to know if this is possible in C or not.

Comment: Using GCC you can instrument your code using `-finstrument-functions` flag. However, the functions that are generated do not receive your functions' argument list. Another option is using preprocessor macros, although you need to explicitly add code to your foo function.

Comment: If you think that any answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it (the green checkmark to the left of the answer). This will indicate to the community that the question has been answered and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Comment: @2501 The answers didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @afsafzal Sorry to hear that. You can use my approach and combine it with code generation to reduce the amount of manual work to a minimum, basically just a list of function names.

Answer (score 0):

Macros can be (ab)used to achieve this in a simplistic way:

```
void foo( int , int );

void Hook( int a , int b )
{
    //do whatever
    foo( a , b );
} 

#define foo( a , b ) Hook( a , b )

int main( void )
{
    foo( 1 , 2 );
}
```

Note that this is error prone and requires careful writing.

Comment: I need a hook that works on all functions in this program, not just one specific one.

Comment: @afsafzal You're gonna have to write a different hook for each function. That is the only way.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
typedef enum FunctionPointerType_E
   {
   FPT_Int_IntInt = 1
   } FunctionPointerTypes_T

int foo(
      int a,
      int b
      )
   {
   return(a+b);
   }

void hook(
      FunctionPointerTypes_T fpt,
      void (*function)(void),
      ...
      )
   {
   int rCode;
   int (*fp_Int_IntInt)(int, int);

   switch(fpt)
     {
     case FPT_Int_IntInt:
        fp_Int_IntInt = (int(*)(int, int))function;
        rCode=(*fp_Int_IntInt)(1,2);
     ...
     }

   return;
   }

void CallFooByRefrence(void)
   {
   hook(FPT_Int_IntInt, (void(*)(void))foo, ...);
   return;
   }
```

Comment: I need a hook that works on all functions in this program, not just one specific one. So I need something where I don't need to specify function's signature.

Comment: There are various ways to do that; but there generally has to be some indication of the return type and parameter type(s) in order to call it by reference.  (updating answer to reflect a solution)